# What is the correct format of the data attribute on a SelectMultipleField

Tags: wtforms

I'm using the custom SelectMultipleField suggested by the documentation.

I can can set the choices perfectly, but I am having real trouble setting the correct format of the data attribute.

```
    class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
        """
        A multiple-select, except displays a list of checkboxes.

        Iterating the field will produce subfields, allowing custom rendering of
        the enclosed checkbox fields.
        """
        widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
        option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

I'm then using:

```
        plist = MultiCheckBoxField(coerce=bool, choices=[('1', '1') ... ])
```

I assumed that .data would be a list of [True, False, False] values, combined with coerce=Bool, but I am getting odd results.

The first value is read as the value for all of the checkboxes.  So if the first value in the list is True, they are all true, and if the first value is False, then all the checkboxes are unticked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the wtforms source, this is what is happening.

```
def process_data(self, value):
    try:
        self.data = list(self.coerce(v) for v in value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        self.data = None
```

So it's not 'filling in' the other values, it is just coercing the array of values you have passed into the form.

If you want the process the data in a different way, override this method.

```
import wtforms

class MultiCheckboxField(wtforms.SelectMultipleField):
    widget = wtforms.widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = wtforms.widgets.CheckboxInput()

    def process_data(self, value):
        try:
            self.data = []

            for choice_value, choice_label in self.choices:
                if choice_value in value:
                    self.data.append(True)
                else:
                    self.data.append(False)
        except:
            self.data = None

class SomeForm(wtforms.Form):
    multi = MultiCheckboxField('', choices=[('val1', 'label'), ('val2', 'label2')], coerce=bool)

f = SomeForm(data={'multi': ['val2']})

>>> f.multi.data
[False, True]
```